# jenkins choice parameterized branch checkout pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hello I recently stated learning pipelines, can anyone help me in writing pipeline for choice parameterized branch checkout, if i checkout master branch, then deploy to some S3 location, else if dev branch to some other location. I have tried but failing here, can anyone please help me.`pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'BRANCH',
            choices: 'Development\nrelease/release_QA\nmaster',
            description: 'Selct the branch to deploy to repective Airflow')
    }
    stages {
        stage('checkout code') {
            steps {
                git(url: 'https://bitbucket.nike.com/scm/something.git', branch: '${params.BRANCH}', credentialsId: '4db2-aec4-7d5e86c4ff4b', changelog: true)
                sh 'ls -al'
            }
        }
    }
}`

I got the following error,

```
 +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/${params.BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/${params.BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/${params.BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

also help me how to write if branch then stages, please..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your `${params.BRANCH}` in double quotes or just use `BRANCH` either of them should work.

*if i checkout master branch, then deploy to some S3 location, else if dev branch to some other location*

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'BRANCH',
            choices: 'Development\nrelease/release_QA\nmaster',
            description: 'Selct the branch to deploy to repective Airflow')
    }
    stages {
        stage('checkout code') {
            steps {
                git(url: 'https://bitbucket.nike.com/scm/something.git', branch: "${params.BRANCH}", credentialsId: '4db2-aec4-7d5e86c4ff4b', changelog: true)
            }   
        }
        stage('Deploy to S3') {
            when {
                expression {
                    BRANCH == 'master'
                }
            }
            // Deploy to S3
        }
        stage('Deploy elsewhere') {
            when {
                expression {
                    BRANCH == 'Development'
                }
            }
            // Deploy elsewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much , can you tell me how to write logic for S3 deployments according to branch , just tell me how to write stage according to branch selection.

thanks again . @ben5556

Comment: Updated my answer to run stage based on branch selected. Please refresh page.

Comment: thank you so much, this is my first time experience with stackoverflow i love your support thank you so much :-)

@ben5556